# How to change the border color of columns line in a table?

Tags: html, css

I only want to change the color of the only column line (the single line in the middle) in this table to blue. How to achieve it? Thanks!

Example table:

````
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
</table>```
````

Comment: Can you share full table code and explain in detail what you need?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.blue {
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table>  
  <tr>
    <th class="blue">Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="blue">Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="blue">Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```css
table {
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
  border-spacing:0;
  font-size:32px;
}

td {
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.highlight td {
  border-color: orange;
}
/* optional enhancment to narrow vertical joined borders*/
td + td {
  border-left:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I hope it works

Answer (score -1):

you can use a `class` html, and if you want to change the font color in css:

```
color: blue;
```

or background color in css:

```
background-color: blue;
```

or border in css:

```
border: 1px solid blue;
```

Comment: `color` works for letters, not for border, OP needs a color for border not the text.

Answer (score -1):

Simply take a class or id and apply your style. that's it.